# How to stop text-boxes in my custom block trailing past the block?

Tags: forms, theming

I am creating a module with a custom block.  Even through googling, I still could not find an answer to my question "how do you theme the elements in a form?"  I think it is the fact that I don't completely understand the array elements that need to be set on each textbox.

Image of my problem: https://www.evernote.com/shard/s188/sh/3bf8cc91-5341-4c55-91ca-41e0ddbd1922/feb9698ff407e60a064f92421510059d

Comment: If you want to reduce length by CSS or make div wider, it's a purely CSS problem, not really Drupal related. Only if you want to make inputs shorter by changing their length parameter, it's actually a Drupal question. But if so, you need to write it more clearly in your question.

Answer (score 0):

While creating this form in your custom module you set DIV class to form items which is textfield in your casy. All you will have to do is use `#prefix` & `#sufix`
You will start your DIV class from `#prefix` before #type of form items & close the DIV at #`sufix`.

Here is the example

```
$form['first_name'] = array(
  '#prefix' => '<div class="demo-form">',
  '#title' => t('First Name'),
   '#type' => 'textfield',
  '#suffix' => '</div>',
  '#maxlength' => 128,
  '#required' => TRUE,
);
```

Open the CSS file or create your own at your theme folder, but if you create your own then you will have to declare it in theme.info file.

Write CSS for the class `demo-form` which you have applied to the form element & resize it as your wish. If you have created your own CSS file then don't forget to clear your cache.

Comment: Turns out I was missing the "#size" array key in the $form['first_name']. Thanks for you contributions!